# GPIO pin numbers for gpiozero class

Tags: gpio, gpiozero

So im trying to learn robotics with raspberrypi and I am following two different guides where I chose the wiring from one guide and the code from the other guide.

My left motor is working but the right one doesn't start and I'm pretty sure its because of the parameters "right" has.
I've checked GPIO pin schemes for raspberry pi with 40 pins and tried different values but it doesnt work.

robot = gpiozero.Robot(left=(17,18), right=(?),(?))

What parameters should right have?

[image]

Comment: gpiozero ALWAYS uses Broadcom numbering for GPIO. So 17/18 refer to GPIO 17/18 (on pins 11/12).  Use https://pinout.xyz/ to map from pin numbers to the GPIO numbers used by the gpiozero module.

Answer (score 2):

Not easy to answer your question because of wire scheme about the projects is necessary. Share with us and I will try to help again.

According to photography, you have nothing plugged to pin 17 and a yellow wire to the 18th pin. They both are the 9th row starting by the left of the photography. You said it works but it shouldn't. I think you could misunderstand the scheme and the motor that you have working isn't left one (could be the right motor but... no idea). **Consider to plug a wire at pin 17 to the 3.3v current.**

Otherwise, next info will help you to figure out how to do properly. That's your Raspberry Pi GPIO scheme:

[image: GPIO Scheme]

Keep in mind the image and check what are the pins you have attached to each motor.

Comment: gpiozero ALWAYS uses Broadcom numbering for GPIO.  So 17/18 refer to GPIO 17/18 (on pins 11/12).

Comment: @Nicolás Rodríguez This is the video that I followed, still cant get it to work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LuQTJSJQYI

Comment: In that case, as @joan said, I think your code couldn't work neither because you only have plugged the GPIO17 (pin #11).